# log4j 1.2 to log4j 2 migration

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I want to upgrade log4j version from 1.2 to 2.3 version. But there are many modules in application (almost 100) and I have 100 log4j.xml files. So I can't change my xml files manually. Can You suggest any automatic way?

Comment: If you're doing common stuff in alot of places, it should be possible with some crazy regex replacement

Comment: Why would you have 100 configuration files instead of just using a single configuration shared by all of them? I think you should think about your long term maintenance plan for this application because I'm sure someday log4j3 will become a reality and you'll need to do this all over again.